# Custom format DateTime to Timestamp

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

I have made many searches for a simple function to convert custom DateTime to Timestamp, But I didn't get the exact solution:

The DateTime str is:

`$dt = "14-05-2015 18:21";`

(Day-Month-Year Hour:Minute) (not the standard DateTime format)

Is there a simple function to convert this string to timestamp?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can't be simpler than:

```
$dt = "14-05-2015 18:21";
echo  strtotime ($dt); //1431627660
```

Comment: But how will PHP tell if the first and the second elements are Day then Month not the opposite? Like in "06-05-2015 18:21"

Comment: from the manual: "Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed. " --please read: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 2):

If format will always be the same, you can do it like this.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i', $dt);
$timestamp = $date->format('U');
```

Comment: the OP already said it wanted a unix timestamp, the `DateTime` class usage is cool, but this is not the OP wanted, just use `U` or `->getTimestamp()`, and why not use `createFromFormat` to avoid ambiguity on the issue of swapping the `d-m`/`m-d`

Comment: @Ghost - Thanks, was just about to change that as well :)